# APNS registered tokens doesn't indentifie a contact in device address book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, apple-push-notifications

The provider register the tokens of each device, that's fine, the server will have a list of unique tokens for each device who has the app.

After the iPhone deliver the token to the provider, I want to search a specific contact on the device to figure out if the contact already have the app installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

no can do, you will need to call back to your web service with the token you are enquiring - if there is a match on your database then bingo, 
sadly you dont have much control over contacts.